# How can I get a single item from an Array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongomapper

I'm using MongoDB and Mongo Mapper and need to find an embedded document inside of an array. There has to be a simpler way to do this than the way I got working which is:

```
@obj.subitems.each do |c|
  if (c.slug.eql? params[:id])
    @subitem = c # this is the variable i need
  end
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@subitem = @obj.subitems.detect { |c| c.slug.eql? params[:id] }
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect

Comment: Thanks! I had seen something about the detect method but it didn't sound like what I was needing. Guess I was wrong.